# HighCharts, Multiple Series, Async Drillup event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a `HighChart` with 3 series for which I'm using the drilldown event to asynchronously get the data for each drilldown series.  I've got this working fine because I can use the drilldown event's, `e.point`s to determine if a single series, or the multiple series is being drilled down into. Thus, I can keep track of where I'm at in the sequence using a `drillDownLevel` counter.

My issue is that on the drillup event, the event `e` does not seem to have any attribute that tells me if I'm drilling back to a single or multiple series, so my `drilldownLevel` count gets decremented wrongly.

This is what I'm doing on drilldown

```
if ( !e.points ) {
     // Single series being drilled down into
     chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point,  data.series[seriesIndexes[e.point.color]]);
     chart.hideLoading();
     chart.applyDrilldown();
     drilldownLevel++;
     lastDrilldownType = 0;
}
else
{
    // Multiple series being drilled down into
    chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, data.series[seriesDrilldownEventCount]);
    seriesDrilldownEventCount++;

    if (seriesDrilldownEventCount === 3) {
         seriesDrilldownEventCount = 0;
         chart.hideLoading();
         chart.applyDrilldown();
         drilldownLevel++;
         lastDrilldownType = 1; 
    }
}
```

This is what I'm doing on drillup

```
if ( lastDrilldownType === 0 ) {

   // Single series being drilled up from
   seriesDrillupEventCount = 0;
   drilldownLevel--;
}
else
{
   // Multiple series being drilled up from

   seriesDrillupEventCount++;
   if (seriesDrillupEventCount === 3) {
        seriesDrillupEventCount = 0;
        drilldownLevel--;
   }
}
```

`lastDrilldownType` ends up being incorrect after a combination of drilling into the multiple series vs single series, and so my `drilldownLevel` count gets messed up.

Does anyone know of how to use the `drillup` event, `e`, to determine what type of series is being drilled back up to?

Comment: As I know, Highcharts will always drillup to all series in the previous level. Consider: http://jsfiddle.net/oscgjwzq/ - doesn't matter if you click on the first column, or the second one, or the category name. Always will drillup to all main series.